# How to use pynput via ssh on an embedded computer

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ssh, pynput

I'm trying to run on an embedded computer (hence with no display) a module using pynput package. I'm connected via ssh to the embedded computer (which is on Linux) and when I try to run the script I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/remi/robot-artificial-intelligence/install/ea_maintenance_mode_manager/lib/ea_maintenance_mode_manager/maintenance_mode", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ea-maintenance-mode-manager==0.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'maintenance_mode')())
  File "/home/remi/robot-artificial-intelligence/install/ea_maintenance_mode_manager/lib/ea_maintenance_mode_manager/maintenance_mode", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/home/remi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 105, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/remi/robot-artificial-intelligence/install/ea_maintenance_mode_manager/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ea_maintenance_mode_manager/maintenance_mode.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pynput import keyboard 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from ._xorg import KeyCode, Key, Controller, Listener
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pynput._util.xorg import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 40, in <module>
    _check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 38, in _check
    display = Xlib.display.Display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 84, in __init__
    name, protocol, host, displayno, screenno = connect.get_display(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 73, in get_display
    return mod.get_display(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 76, in get_display
    raise error.DisplayNameError(display)
Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""
```

I know that this error is because on Linux pynput uses X to control the keyboard and an environnement variable $DISPLAY is created.
So I wanted to set it when running the script remotely (after being connected via ssh) :

```
DISPLAY=":0" python3 path_to_my_script/my-script.py
```

After running this line I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/ea_maintenance_mode_manager/ea_maintenance_mode_manager/maintenance_mode.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pynput import keyboard 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from ._xorg import KeyCode, Key, Controller, Listener
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pynput._util.xorg import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 40, in <module>
    _check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 38, in _check
    display = Xlib.display.Display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 166, in __init__
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": b'No protocol specified\n'
```

When I connect directly to the embedded computer and type in term :

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

I get `:0`

Is there a way to emulate a display via ssh to use the package pynput ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use [sshkeyboard](https://github.com/ollipal/sshkeyboard) library instead of pynput as it does not require X server or DISPLAY value to be set. It has some same features as pynput such as reacting to the user input, but it cannot for example mock key presses.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on a similar problem.  I gather pynput required a X server running and using Xvfb to start a virtual X server may resolve, but I do not have working yet.

Comment: Perhaps it's not my place, but why are you answering if you don't really have an answer?

Comment: It was a step I think he's missing from me trying to solve my own problem.  Not a complete solution, but maybe enough for him.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even thought I did not use it, I got around the problem by using an embedded display. So this question is still open.

Comment: [This thread] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427345/keyboard-monitoring-without-display)might be helpful. My case is even if you can connect with X server without any error, the pynput listener still won't work.